# SVG rendering issue

Tags: html, svg

On our internal ticket system I have created a bunch of SVG's (one for each department) and they render perfectly on my screen. However, my colleagues get completely different looking SVG's on the same platform (Windows) and same browser (chrome). I've searched Google for similar problems but I'm getting nothing, has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Your question is vary vague. You need to be more specific and add more details to it to hope to get an answer.

Comment: I dont know how i can be more specific about this. I have an SVG; I am using windows 10 and browsing with Chrome, my colleagues; also using windows 10 and Chrome, are seeing something different on screen that i am. If I could give more details I would but thats all i've got. I'm trying to find out if anyone else has had this issue, if you haven't then thats fine

Comment: If you and they view the source of the SVG is it the same or different? Is the file request from the server the same or different?

Comment: same source, different result. same server request

Comment: In what way is it different? Fonts are not the always the same and DPI could affect things as well.

Comment: Things you could do to make this question better: (1) explain how they are "different" (2) Post a screenshot, (3) Post the SVG, (4) Post a code snippet reproducing the problem.